# Who chooses the host for the Oscar show?

Tags: academy-awards

This year Barney, I mean Neil Patrick Harris, hosted the Oscars award show.

Who produces the show and who gets to choose the host? It seems like quite a responsibility.

Comment: Seems like a thankless job. If your nominee for host does well, he/she gets the glory; if they bomb, they don't get called back next year, and you get canned.

Comment: The same people who told the gorilla that he couldn't go to the ballet.

Comment: I still don't get why Doogie Howser changed his name to Barney.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The Oscars are presented by the [Academy of Motion Picture Arts and Sciences](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Academy_of_Motion_Picture_Arts_and_Sciences), which hires producers to create the awards ceremony. The producers are in charge of the entire production, including selecting a host.  For the past few years [Craig Zadan](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Craig_Zadan) and [Neil Meron](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neil_Meron) have been the producers of the Oscars. A recent article in *The Hollywood Reporter* briefly outlined the selection process that led to Neil Patrick Harris hosting the 87th Academy Awards show.

Reference: [Neil Patrick Harris Wasn't Academy's First Choice to Host the Oscars](http://www.hollywoodreporter.com/news/neil-patrick-harris-wasnt-academys-742768).